# why image is not transparent

Tags: node-editor

I have added the png transparent image with the setting and its not showing transparent black background is seen. I have the base color aluminum and i want to add that logo of png on to it. The image is black letter with transparent background why its showing in white letters and black background. May i know where im going wrong any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To have a transparent background you need a transparent shader.

[image]

To overlay the image on top the color used on a shader

[image]

Using the same principle you just need to add the color to the existing underlaying material, using the alpha channel to mix it.

(remember to assign the material to that part of the mesh ).

[image]

Comment: but still the background is black not transparent

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86315/change-opacity-transparent-image-texture/86348#86348 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: The result u shown is good. The problem below the logo i need the aluminum material and on that top i want the logo. As i think there is not material below so i cant seen clear.

Comment: @ateks you know how this site works... if you make a clear question you get better answers.

Comment: @ateks see edited answer.

Comment: Thats what need.But as i can notice the color have the image in that i just need the aluminum color only. And the logo also not black looks grey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63364/discussion-between-ateks-and-cegaton).