# How do I make my reference image transparent?

Tags: 3d-view, image, transparency

Looking to 3D model this Mega Man helmet and trying to find a way to make my refrence image transparent. Specifically looking to use OR add the "Object Data" tool but is nowhere to be found. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143836/how-to-make-semitransparency-on-an-image-plane-of-a-2d-png-in-v2-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a Transparent BSDF and a Mix Shader to the node setup of the material of the texture (and set the Blend Mode to a type of Alpha if it isn't already). Then changing the Fac value of the Mix Shader will also give control over the amount of transparency.

[image]

Comment: My reference image has no material, and the three chain-linked similar questions all require the image to have a material. How do I add a material to my image?

Answer (score 0):

Save your image as a .png file  then in the Opacity data property click the Opacity checkbox and adjust slider accordingly. [image]