# How do I make objects transparent in edit mode in 2.8

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I want to be able to make objects transparent to see my reference image better. I can't seem to find anything though.

Comment: you need to either switch to Wireframe mode, or to Solid mode and give it trasparency (alt Z). You can set the amount of transparency in the Viewport Shading panel.

Comment: As @moonboots said, (with your ref. as an Image Empty, not imported as a plane)

Comment: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187451/how-do-i-make-my-reference-image-transparent/187466#187466) might help. With materials you have more control over what happens to individual objects. it's the image made transparent here, but you can do it for any object

Answer (score 1):

You could Toggle X-Ray, located in the 3D Viewport Header. Or click the little downward pointing ">" icon to open the Viewport Shading panel and check the box next to X-ray. Or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image]

As stated by moonboots, in the Viewport Shading panel you can also change the amount of transparency.

(moonboots comment was quite adequate but i though they made a mistake, while actualy i had my keybindings messed up: apologies)